# minimum next greater element in O(nlog(n))

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Spent hours on this so far and still struggling. I could do this easily in O(n^2) but the challenge is to do in O(nlog(n)) time.

1. Unsorted Array
2. Need to find the index of the minimum `A[j]` such that `A[j] > A[i]` and `j > i` for every element in the Unsorted Array

So essentially the smallest of the elements greater than an element and to the right of it in an array.

If an element cannot be found, the index is -1.

The result is an array of corresponding index values for what we're looking for.

Example:

```
Input: [80; 19; 49; 45; 65; 71; 76; 28; 68; 66]
Output: [-1; 7; 4; 4; 9; 6; -1; 9; -1; -1]
```

Current attempts are scanning through the Input array and creating a Value-Index Pair for each element, insert them into a new array and sort that over the values. Then maybe some variant of Binary Search or self-balancing BST, but the actual solution just isn't coming to mind.

This is a slight variation on the Next Greater Element problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd suggest going from right to left, and adding the values to a data structure that has O(logN) insertion and look-up time, like a BST.

Comment: Iterate from right to left, and for each element, add a pair of the element and its index into an `std::set` after you search the set using `upper_bound`.

Comment: - Minor grammar correction
- Fixed formatting in example

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding smallest next bigger element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52677426/finding-smallest-next-bigger-element)

Answer (score 1):

I think this question is very similar to finding the successor of a node. If you can imagine that all the values in the array are inside a BalancedBST something like an AVL tree for example. 
The only trick here is that we need to find the successor from the values that are on the right of a number in an array. So the trick here is to actually query for from right to left.

So we start from the very last element of the array put it inside the BST and then query for the successor of that element. Keep doing this for each element from right to left in the array.

This would result in O(NlgN)as insertion as well as finding successor in a BST is logN in worst case.

Answer (score 0):

Start traversing array from right to left and keep inserting elements in set and for each element find its upper bound in set and that will be minimum next greater element of current index.

**Algorithm:**

```
for i = n to 1
   ans[i] = set.upper_bound(arr[i])
   set.insert(arr[i])
return ans
```

*Time Complexity: O(nlogn)*