# Finding smallest next bigger element

Tags: c++, algorithm, indexing, data-structures, tree

I have a task which requires me to find the smallest of all bigger elements in an array for all array entries and store the respective indexes in an array and I can't quite figure out the last part of the solution.

This is kind of similar to the problem explained here:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/smallest-greater-elements-in-whole-array/

The only difference is that only the values right of the array entry are accounted for (j>i), e.g.:

```
input:  [80; 19; 49; 45; 65; 71; 76; 28; 68; 66]  
output: [-1;  7;  4;  4;  9;  6; -1;  9; -1; -1]
```

The solution with a self balancing tree makes sense to me. However, I still need to account for the indexing because only the solutions right of the array entry are valid.

Is there a way to map the indexing of the inserted values to the tree entries or to create a second tree with an identical structure but the index of the old array entries instead of the actual values as nodes? I am not sure because the structure of the self-balancing tree of course depends on the values inserted (bigger values right subtree, smaller values left subtree).

EDIT: Actually a second AVL tree propably won't help as I have to check that indexing is bigger AND array entry is bigger while traversing the tree...

Comment: Do you have to use a tree instead of an array? Please provide a sample input and output you desire. What programming language do you use?

Comment: Sample Input: [80; 19; 49; 45; 65; 71; 76; 28; 68; 66]

Sample Output: [-1; 7; 4; 4; 9; 6; -1; 9; -1; -1]

-1 for entries which dont have a greater element on the left side. Programing language would be C++ because there are libraries for abstract data types like stacks or AVL-trees. I can also use an array. For example do a sort on the array (which is basically done by the avl tree or any other type of self-balancing binary search tree) and use binary search for the same purpose.

Comment: I mean right side of course

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to iterate over the input from right to left, and for each element look up the first greater element in a tree (or any data structure with O(LogN) look-up and insertion), and then add the element to the tree. That way the greater element always comes after the element in the input.

For a C++ version, you can use a `std::map` where the element's value is the key and the element's index in the input is the value, and use `upper_bound` to get the next greater value:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

void nextValues(std::vector<int> &in, std::vector<int> &out) {
    std::map<int, int> tree;
    for (int i = in.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        out.insert(out.begin(), tree.upper_bound(in[i])->second - 1);
        tree.insert(std::pair<int, int>(in[i], i + 1));
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> a = {80,19,49,45,65,71,76,28,68,66};
    std::vector<int> b;
    nextValues(a, b);
    for (int i : b) std::cout << (int) i << ","; // -1,7,4,4,9,6,-1,9,-1,-1
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thats brilliant. So you use a hashtable structure like the map to store the indexing in the required order. My solution would've included building an array with the original indexing by applying binary search for every element in a on the sorted array and then performing a NGE algorithm on that array but this is much more elegant. Thank you very much !

Comment: @Rob You could do the same thing with a simple BST where each node holds both the value and the index of an element, and you could even combine the look-up and the insertion into one action. But if there's something in the standard library that works, you might as well use it :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it with the same logic as that geeks for geeks article in this way:

```
vector<int> findLeastGreater(vector<int>& arr, int n) {
        // similar to Smallest greater elements in whole array
        // except, add to set from last element to first
        // after each addition to set, find it+1 for each array index
        vector<int> res(n, -1);
        set<int> s;
        s.insert(arr[n-1]);
        for (int i = n-2; i >= 0; i--) {
            int curr = arr[i];
            s.insert(curr);
            auto it = s.find(curr);
            it++;
            if (it != s.end()) {
                res[i] = *it;
            } 
        }
        return res;
        
    }
```