# Is there a solution with better time complexity for the problem below:

Tags: algorithm, performance

There an input integer array, You have to make an output array which indicates for every value in input array how many indices to wait to get a higher value.If there is not a higher value till the end of input array, put -1

Example:

input:[10, 8, 6, 8, 8, 11, 9]
output:[5, 4, 1, 2, 1, -1, -1]

input:[6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
output:[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]

input:[6, 3, 51, 42, 3, 22, 12]
output:[2, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1]

I have come up with a simple solution below with O(n2) time complexity in worst case. Is there a better solution?

```
def func(input_arr):
output_arr = []
for p in range(0, len(input_arr)):
    found = False
    for i in range(p+1, len(input_arr)):
        if input_arr[i]>input_arr[p]:
            found = True
            output_arr.append(i-p)
            break
    if not found:
        output_arr.append(-1)
return output_arr
```

Comment: For improving working code I'd suggest [codereview.se] - this site here is only for fixing broken code.

Comment: @Filburt I think asking for efficient algorithms is on-topic here.

Comment: Since this is asking for the index, not the value of the higher element, it's more a duplicate of e.g. this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52677426/finding-smallest-next-bigger-element/52683236